# Laravel 8 redirect to custom route on failed login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Today I've had a problem and want to share solution, because I'm sure somebody will need this in future.

I have login form in bootstrap modal on my website for example `localhost`. After I type bad credentials, the page just refreshes, but I want it to redirect to `/login` and show error message.

I was searching the net for this trick, but not found anything for laravel 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Modify yourproject/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php

before:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
     throw ValidationException::withMessages([
         $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
     ]);
}
```

after:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('/login')
         ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
         ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
         ]);
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think it's good practice to modify the files under `vendor`